# SOAP client request with foreach loop inside array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

I need SOAP request to look like this:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:sgd="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SGDDWebServiceContracts.Messages" xmlns:sgd9="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SGDDWebServiceContracts.DataTypes.ProductStock">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <tem:RequestProductStock>
        <tem:criteria>
            <sgd:Values>
                <sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                    <sgd9:ProductNumber>0123456789-1</sgd9:ProductNumber>
                    <sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>MY-SECRET-KEY</sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>
                    <sgd9:SellerCompany>static</sgd9:SellerCompany>
                </sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                <sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                    <sgd9:ProductNumber>0123456789-2</sgd9:ProductNumber>
                    <sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>MY-SECRET-KEY</sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>
                    <sgd9:SellerCompany>static</sgd9:SellerCompany>
                </sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                <sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                    <sgd9:ProductNumber>0123456789-3</sgd9:ProductNumber>
                    <sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>MY-SECRET-KEY</sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>
                    <sgd9:SellerCompany>static</sgd9:SellerCompany>
                </sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
            </sgd:Values>
        </tem:criteria>
    </tem:RequestProductStock>
</x:Body>
```

ProductNumber needs to be inserted with foreachloop, rest is static.

I need to run foreachloop inside multiarray like this:

```
$productSkus = array("0123456789-1","0123456789-2","0123456789-3","0123456789-4","0123456789-5","0123456789-6","0123456789-7","0123456789-8","0123456789-9","0123456789-10");

    $params = array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'Values' => array(
                'ProductStockCriteria' => array(
                    'ProductNumber' => FOREACHLOOP HERE, 
                    'SecurityKeyAPI' => 'MY-SECRET-KEY',
                    'SellerCompany' => 'static'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

So far i have this, but it is not working. Think i have lost my clue here.:

```
    $params = array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'Values' => array()
            )
        )
    );

    foreach (productSkus as $sku) {
        $params['criteria']['Values'][] = array(
            'ProductStockCriteria' => array(
                'ProductNumber' => $sku, 
                'SecurityKeyAPI' => 'MY-SECRET-KEY',
                'SellerCompany' => 'static'
            )
        );
    }
```

Anyone can see what i am doing wrong? I need to build static array firstm and then after insert dynamic values with foreach iteration correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found out myself.

This is my solution. Need to build array in 2 parts.

**1) MAKING STATIC ARRAY (PARENT)**

```
$params = array(
    'criteria' => array(
        'Values' => array(
            'ProductStockCriteria' => array()
        )
    )
);
```

**2) BUILDING DYNAMIC PARTS WITH A FOREACH (CHILDS)**

```
$productSkus = array("0123456789-1","0123456789-2","0123456789-3","0123456789-4","0123456789-5","0123456789-6","0123456789-7","0123456789-8","0123456789-9","0123456789-10");

foreach ($productSkus as $sku ) {
    $params['criteria']['Values']['ProductStockCriteria'][] = array(
        'ProductNumber' => $sku, 
        'SecurityKeyAPI' => 'MY-API-KEY',
        'SellerCompany' => 'static'
    );
}
```

This will create a SOAP request like this:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:sgd="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SGDDWebServiceContracts.Messages" xmlns:sgd9="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SGDDWebServiceContracts.DataTypes.ProductStock">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
<tem:RequestProductStock>
    <tem:criteria>
        <sgd:Values>
            <sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                <sgd9:ProductNumber>0123456789-1</sgd9:ProductNumber>
                <sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>MY-SECRET-KEY</sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>
                <sgd9:SellerCompany>static</sgd9:SellerCompany>
            </sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
            <sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                <sgd9:ProductNumber>0123456789-2</sgd9:ProductNumber>
                <sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>MY-SECRET-KEY</sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>
                <sgd9:SellerCompany>static</sgd9:SellerCompany>
            </sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
            <sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
                <sgd9:ProductNumber>0123456789-3</sgd9:ProductNumber>
                <sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>MY-SECRET-KEY</sgd9:SecurityKeyAPI>
                <sgd9:SellerCompany>static</sgd9:SellerCompany>
            </sgd9:ProductStockCriteria>
        </sgd:Values>
    </tem:criteria>
</tem:RequestProductStock>
```